# Typescript: Reference type of property by other property of same object

Tags: typescript

See the following code:

```
interface X {
    a: string;
    b: number;
    c: boolean;
}

type A = {
    prop: keyof X;
    value: X[keyof X];
}

const a: A = { prop: 'a', value: 'a' }; // ok
const b: A = { prop: 'a', value: 1 }; // not ok, value should be string, because X['a'] is string
const c: A = { prop: 'b', value: 1 }; // ok
const d: A = { prop: 'c', value: 1 }; // not ok, value should be boolean, because X['c'] is boolean
```

Here I want the type of the `.value` property to be `string`, if `prop` is `"a"`, `number` for `"b"` and `boolean` for `"c"`, but instead it is `string|number|boolean` for all cases, because `keyof X` can refer to different keys for each use for `type A`. How can I make it refer to the same property twice, without having it explicitly input it into a generic argument of `A`?

I feel like I should be using `infer` her, but I'm not sure how, and also I might be on the wrong track there.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want `A` to be a [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of `{prop: K; value: X[K]}` for each `K` in `keyof X`, like this:

```
type A = {
    prop: "a";
    value: string;
} | {
    prop: "b";
    value: number;
} | {
    prop: "c";
    value: boolean;
};
```

In each element of that union, there is a correlation between the `prop` type and the `value` type, which prohibits you from assigning `prop` and `value` types from different members of `X`:

```
const a: A = { prop: 'a', value: 'a' }; // ok
const b: A = { prop: 'a', value: 1 }; // error
const c: A = { prop: 'b', value: 1 }; // ok
const d: A = { prop: 'c', value: 1 }; // error
```

---

You can also make the compiler calculate this for you programmatically in a few ways, such as building a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) that you immediately [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html):

```
type A = { [K in keyof X]-?: {
    prop: K;
    value: X[K];
} }[keyof X];
```

It can be verified via IntelliSense that the above definitions of `A` are equivalent, but now `A` will update automatically if you modify `X`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4FgBQz-JwBcyAzmFKAOYDcuByARiSAK4C2j0deBCJjAPaCANhDggeAX1y4wATwAOKAILIAvJmQBtANLJQyANYR5gmGgC6AWgD8JbL3yKogxSV08GANzgjWECSoepbSyFLaJmYWqKGyOAD0AFTICsrIapqODC5uJABEcPleBL7+gWQU1GEAPpj0BLnuyPmMxQ34ZQEsHFxQtfVOyE0FCO1DXRVCouKSuFLISQnxCIIg5IQkmVojyADkcHsANMiTJAd74TTICQnIgka4q+tgTFsaO67NFydnyACMVxud2grigTzWG34GQ+GGGX3OjGOpz83QBQNu90eOGeGwAJu8svC8vsEMi-oCpNdMaDBOCcEA)

Comment: This really helped me with making types more robust while writing a generic table component, thank you! Particularly, making sure a custom cell `render` function can tell what the type of the `cell` is based on the `key` passed in the same object. See here for a related discussion: https://github.com/vuejs/core/discussions/8851

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe you can do this without generics. So here it is:

```
type A<K extends keyof X> = {
    prop: K;
    value: X[K];
}
```

The good news is, you only need to specify the generic argument when you're assigning to a variable of an explicitly given type, like so:

```
const a: A<'a'> = { prop: 'a', value: 'a' };
```

And it's possible that you will never have this need in your code. For example if you specify a function using this generic type, you will not need to explicitly specify the generic parameter to get it working:

```
function fn<K extends keyof X>(a: A<K>) {
    // something
}

fn({ prop: 'a', value: 'a' }); // ok
fn({ prop: 'a', value: 1 }); // not ok, value should be string, because X['a'] is string
fn({ prop: 'b', value: 1 }); // ok
fn({ prop: 'c', value: 1 }); // not ok, value should be boolean, because X['c'] is string
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=24&ssc=90&pln=17&pc=1#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgBrIN4Chm%20XALmQGcwpQBzAbhzwCMiQBXAWzuhr2QSLoHs%20AGwhwQNAL5YsYAJ4AHFAEEAPAGlkEAB6QQAE2LIA1hBl8YaAHzIAvJlq45UPnKKrOeAG5xBTCEVQA2qoAuhJSCHwgpPhEKgDkcHFWthjIjs5ECXEANMhePn7IWcjiVMgA9OXIfIZYEVFgyAzI8YnJmGlOLkWJufm%20RACMJWWVyCB8jTV93r4kABZ8TIK6TSik5CAUuewIcEzEKIFZwcjABhuUdZHRPC3KcXRJNh3p3Y85ebOFw6UVVTVrg1kLpYg8EM8Up0MkUITMCkMRv9xpNqoZ4XNiItlqt2E0BMJRDsIHsDkcAnEIadziQyFcsDAmCAEGBgJFkDAQGoNNoIHoDMZTOZUBYABSEe6qCwASjsXDGxD4LAgYHmV0kDJAotSb0yvS%20CJ6cRK0tGANqnO10Pe%20v6PxNZpRU3RBsx2JWa1pm22a1JhzQFMS1IudK2mqtuqKTwx9vEpuRgMtOq6mThrtj8bGE2dMYWSw9eP4QhEIGJfvJlLiwa9VyAA)

Comment: I'm going to accept this one as the solution. Using a helper function is an interesting approach I hadn't thought about. I also like this solution because the compiler error is exactly what I want it to be. It complains only about the value property, and tells you what it should be, whereas in the other solution the error message is much more vague. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Your final goal of A is this type. (the same as first answer)

```rb
type A = {
    prop: "a";
    value: string;
} | {
    prop: "b";
    value: number;
} | {
    prop: "c";
    value: boolean;
};
```

To make this type,

1. Define `PropValuePairOfX`

   ```rb
   type PropValuePairOfX<K extends keyof X> = { prop: K; value: X[K] };
   ```
2. Define `PropValuePairMapOfX`.

   ```
   type PropValuePairMapOfX = { [K in keyof X]: PropValuePairOfX<K> };
   // {
   //   a: {prop: 'a', value: string},
   //   b: {prop: 'b', value: number},
   //   c: {prop: 'c', value: boolean}
   // }
   ```
3. At last, `PropValuePairsOfX` to extract `PropValuePairMapOfX` ’s values as UnionType.

   ```
   // This type is the same as A
   type PropValuePairsOfX = PropValuePairMap[keyof X];
   //  {prop: 'a', value: string} | {prop: 'b', value: number} | {prop: 'c', value: boolean}
   //  This type is the same as our goal type 

   const a: PropValuePairsOfX = { prop: 'a', value: 'a' }; // ok
   const b: PropValuePairsOfX = { prop: 'a', value: 1 }; // not ok, value should be string, because X['a'] is string
   const c: PropValuePairsOfX = { prop: 'b', value: 1 }; // ok
   const d: PropValuePairsOfX = { prop: 'c', value: 1 }; // not ok, value should be boolean, because X['c'] is string
   ```
4. (Option) By making X generic argument type, we can make more general type.

   ```
   interface X {
     a: string;
     b: number;
     c: boolean;
   }

   type PropValuePair<T, K extends keyof T> = { prop: K; value: T[K] };
   type PropValuePairMap<T> = { [K in keyof T]: PropValuePair<T, K> };
   type PropValuePairsUnion<T> = PropValuePairMap<T>[keyof T];

   const validA: PropValuePairsUnion<X> = { prop: 'a', value: 'a' }; // ok
   const invalidA: PropValuePairsUnion<X> = { prop: 'a', value: 0 }; // ng
   ```